# How to draw use case for two systems?

Tags: uml

[image: example use case that I have draw]

I am new to business analyst. Currently I have a project that needs to communicate between systems. Based on my use case, I have 2 systems and 1 data centre.

`Client A` can use `System1` and `System2`. If `client A` makes a withdraw through `System1`, `System 1` needs to send the details to the `Data Centre`.

`Client A` also can make a withdraw through `System2` and `System2` needs to send the details to the `Data Centre`. The `Data Centre` is basically the place where `System1` and `System2` submit their details to. Of course, it has a rule that `System1` and `System2` can't send and receive the details directly without the `Data Centre`. Can I draw it out like this?

Comment: Besides the fact, that the above has lots of flaws:: UCs are shown as ellipsis. The symbol above is a (compressed) activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *use case diagram* is invalid, a *use case diagram* doesn't show exchanges, for that use a *deployment diagram* for instance :

[image]

---

The *Data Center* is a secondary actor if is not part of your global system (contrarily to *System1* and *System2*) :

[image]

If *Data Center* is part of your global system it doesn't not appear in the diagram because this is part of the implementation. The use cases show *what* must be done rather than *how* it is done.

Comment: One would wonder if the two Withdraw UCs are actually different. What bloody company would offer two different systems for withdrawal where a single would do? The goal for both would be "client gets cash".

Comment: So in short: upvote for the first part, down for the 2nd.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I have the same interrogation as you about the equality or inequality of the systems, only the OP knows ... perhaps ^^. As you can see in the deployment diagram I use two instances of the same type, and I used the other possibility in the second diagram

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with the 1st part of your answer. The 2nd shows `System1` and `2` which are for sure just implementation/deployment details and have no place in a UC diagram. There shall be only one System Under Consideration. And following only one "Withdraw cash" (verb-only UCs are not the best ones) UC.

Comment: @ThomasKilian The *global* system described at UC level can be composed by what the OP (badly) name system1 and system2 and may be data center. Note system1 and system2 are only *subject* in my diagram. The problem can be just in the naming from the OP

Comment: haha. it can't be a single system because of system1 and system2 use different company and different architecture

Comment: @ThomasKilian, well, I can imagine a situation where there are two competing systems. For example you have ATM machines from different vendors or different systems for different card operators (e.g. one for Visa and a different one for AmEx). Anyway I would probably simply build UC for each of the systems separately.

Comment: @Ister Still nope. The use case is the same. This is an implementation "detail". You won't make a technical design during use case synthesis.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after showing use cases, then there is only one you named `Withdraw`.

Use Cases show a single added value for an actor which is dealing with the system under consideration (SUC). From a business perspective you don't care about technical details. You will put that into requirements like `{ ATM must be used }` etc. But you're actually only after the goal behind the UC in the first place. Next would be to describe scenarios how that goal could be achieved. Only then you care about (program) technic. Please also note that verb-only use cases are not a good choice. Use a predicate-subject(-object) form, so in your case `Withdraw money`.

[image]

That being said (I recommend reading Bitter/Spence about use cases as always) it rather looks like you are doing a technical documentation of an existing system. You can do that by showing devices

[image]

Note the multiplicity that says there's one data center and any number of ATMs. Now what actually happens between the components can be detailed by using sequence diagrams, using interfaces and things like that. Details are too many to be shown/explained here.

Comment: yes... I have messed up with technical documentation. I should realize now I am doing a BRD. btw, thanks for suggesting me a Bitter/Spence book. A good book to learn deeply about use case modelling